# How to finally disable all spell correction on OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spell-checking, evernote

I disabled spell correction at OSX Settings;

[image]

I am not able to disable spell correction in Chrome or Evernote for instance because the menu items are disabled:

[image]

So while typing i am getting always corrected automatically both in Google Chrome and Evernote and it is very annoying, because the spelling correction is mostly incorrect (and has very strange and confusing results sometimes).

How can I finally disable all spell correction on OSX Yosemite including Apps like Chrome and Evernote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Check Spelling While Typing" menu option is not available to you unless you are focused in the app somewhere you can enter text. Go to Chrome and Evernote, find a place where you can enter text (like a note in Evernote, or a comment box on this site in Chrome), and the menu option should become available to you.

This is unrelated to the checkbox you disabled in System Preferences. That controls whether auto-correct is enabled. That's separate from the spell-checker which marks possible errors while you type, but does not perform auto-correction in realtime while you type.

Comment: For Evernote and Chrome in particular, go the the menu bar up top and Click "Edit" > "Spelling and Grammar" > "Show Spelling and Grammar"